# WSE service update; "wse" suffix issue

Tags: .net, web-services

I have an application that references a web service using WSE 3.0 (VS2k5 and .Net 2.0).  The application, which is a third-party app, contains a reference to the proxy object "ThisServiceWse", when I update the web service reference the proxy object name is changed to "ThisService", without the "Wse" suffix.  This implies that the project is not using WSE even though the project properties say otherwise.  Has anyone seen this?  How do I fix it?  I've already tried uninstalling/reinstalling WSE to no avail.

Also, as a side question.  I can't upgrade this service because it utilizes the "RequireMTOM" property.  Is it possible to set this property in .Net 3.5 web services?  Would love to upgrade from WSE 3.0.

Comment: I have this same problem, and it would be nice if someone had something other than a non-answer.  I managed to make this work about a year ago, under VS2005, but when I moved the project to VS2008 the WSE version of the service disappeared.  Wish I could remember what I did to make it work...

Comment: Anyone found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Ryan, WSE is obsolete. It was replaced by WCF the moment WCF shipped. WCF it very different from WSE, so it's unlikely that the "RequireMTOM" property still exists in that form.

Also, if you updated a "Service Reference", then you're not using WSE on the client - you're using WCF on the client.

Comment: Sorry John, this is not WCF, I meant "Web Service Reference", sorry if I confused you.

Also, there are still ASMX services in .net 3.5, so that would be what I would upgrade to, not WCF.

Comment: @Ryan: I'm confused again. Are you aware that ASMX services do not support MTOM? And, believe it or not, you would be making a mistake to do any new development using ASMX services. They're not obsolete yet, but they're getting close.

Comment: @John, I wasn't aware ASMX doesn't support MTOM, hence my question ;) .  Since this is a brownfield app that already utilizes ASMX its a lot more cost effective to just "upgrade" them....however, I don't fully understand what dropping the "RequireMTOM" property will do to the application.  I understand it's an encoding, but will the app explode without it?

Comment: MTOM is a means of encoding large amounts of data, or attachments. Without knowing your application, I don't know if that would affect it. Also, it's possible that WSE was used for some other reason that was good at the time. For instance, without WSE, ASMX only supports SSL security, and nothing else. If security had been a requirement, then ASMX is not a solution - WCF _is_. I strongly suggest you learn more about the requirements and these technologies, or you may be making a big, expensive mistake.